# SOQl query to compare multiselect picklist with a variable

Tags: soql

I have a string  field says ServiceSegment = 'A' and a multiselect picklist Service_segment__c ='A;B;C'. I want to write a SOQL query which can compate string field to multiselect picklist.
I tried this and getting error:

```
list<User> UsersInContext = [Select firstname, lastname, Related_BDE__c, Related_Team__c,Service_Segment__c, id 
                                                            from 
                                                            User 
                                                            where 
                                                            isactive = true 
                                                            AND
                                                            Service_Segment__c.split(';') =: serviceSegment
                                                            AND
                                                            On_Leave__c = false
                                                            order by 
                                                            Related_Team__c asc];
```

getting error unexpected token (;). please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
Service_Segment__c includes (:serviceSegment)
```

See the [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) documentation for the detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use .split() in a SOQL query. I can't see a way to elegantly do this with a single SOQL query, so I think you'll need to loop through the records and check them individually.

You may need to tweak the syntax a little as I've just quickly typed this up, but this should be the general idea I think:

```
List<User> UsersInContext = [
    SELECT 
        firstname, 
        lastname, 
        Related_BDE__c, 
        Related_Team__c,
        Service_Segment__c, 
        id 
    FROM 
        User 
    WHERE 
        isactive = true 
    AND
        On_Leave__c = false
    ORDER BY 
        Related_Team__c ASC
];

for (User u : UsersInContext) {

    Set<String> serviceSegmentValues = new Set<String>(u.Service_Segment__c.split(';'));

    for (String str : serviceSegmentValues) {

        if (str == serviceSegment) {

            // Matching value found - do something with this User
        }
    }
}
```